# LGPL Xuggle : ConverterFactory.createConverter not supported

Tags: java, ffmpeg, xuggler, xuggle

I am using Xuggle to create an mpeg-ts stream.
Everything was working nice until I realized that I was using the GPL version of ffmpeg, which I cannot.

So I recompiled the whole library, and removed the --enable-nonfree and --enable-gpl flags from ffmpeg.

The thing is that now my code would throw an error at me.

The lines in question are :

```
image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
IVideoPicture outFrame = ConverterFactory.createConverter(image, IPixelFormat.Type.YUV420P).toPicture(image, timeStamp);
```

And the error I get is

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Converter class com.xuggle.xuggler.video.BgrConverter constructor failed with: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: IVideoResampler not supported in this build
    at com.xuggle.xuggler.video.ConverterFactory.createConverter(ConverterFactory.java:347)
```

The thing is that we were using the same code with the 3.3 version of Xuggle, and even though ffmpeg was throwing warnings at us saying that we had no hardware acceleration, everything was working fine.

So did something important change between those versions? 
And how can I overcome this? I searched in the archive but couldn't find related issues so far.

Thanks!

Comment: I have been having trouble even building an LGPL version of the Xuggler jar file. Do you have one you can share @jlengrand?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. My LGPL version contains some patches, but I   will try to make one available to you soon

Comment: That would be super helpful! Thanks @jlengrand!

Comment: Hey. Better late than never :). Here is a zip containing a LGPL version of Xuggle. You want to use the biggest jar, because it contains the dll . https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4286043/lgpl_stanag.zip Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the color space converter bundled with FFmpeg in Xuggle 3.x is ONLY active in GPL mode.  Why FFmpeg does that, I don't know.  But it means if you cannot use the GPL version of FFmpeg, then you cannot use the color space converter in Xuggle (since that's what we use).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is indeed what I feared. So what kind of work-around could be applied? How do Xuggle users do usualy in that case? I couldn't find any info about that :s